# Using a Git hook to create a commit log and add to the current commit

Tags: git, bash, shell

I'm running this shell script whenever I do a `git commit -m "msg"` which writes the commit log to a php file. I want it to include the current commit message as well that I am doing at that time.

My shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
path="path/to/gitlog.php"
echo "<?php $git_log = array(" > $path
git log --date=iso --pretty=format:'array("%h","%an","%ad","%s"),' >> $path
echo ");" >> $path
```

The gitlog.php gets saved to my repository, which I will then `git push`.

I currently have it in 'pre-commit' hook, is there a way to get the committing message within this hook?

**My use case**

I am the only developer in the project. Time is short! it's for others who are involved in the project to see progress and read the descriptive commit logs without the overhead of me having to double up. The log is output to a dashboard that everyone has access to.

Git is not running on the dashboard server, and files are deployed from a repository hosting company (Beanstalk)

Comment: A pre-commit hook runs before the commit, so it can't possibly include the commit itself.  You can make a new, additional commit *after* you've made the commit, and you can even make that new commit have a different parent than the most recent commit (this is how `git commit --amend` works), but you can't change the existing commit.  If you're trying to include version information, the usual method with git is to keep that file outside git, especially if the entire file is generated from a commit (as this one would be).  To view an old commit you check it out, then run your "generate version".

Comment: @torek, thks - is there not a hook that gets called before the actual commit is performed, and gets passed the message data, that I can manually append the commit message and date to the log, re-perform the  'git add .' and finally continue with the committing?

Comment: Aha, yes, there's the `commit-msg` hook.  It's intended to let you alter the message (for formatting standards) or reject the commit if the message is wrong.  I have never actually used this hook myself but it runs at the right point in the commit process.  I would recommend not doing `git add .` (that might add files you are deliberately leaving modified-but-not-staged) but `git add $path` might well work here.  (I'd suggest testing with commits of specific files as well, though, and/or `git commit -a`, to see if it works right there.)

Comment: There are several problems with trying to use hooks for generating something like changelog. They will tend to generate a lot of changes, that will get in your way during merging and don't forget that they are local to repository and have to be set on each repository separately. Depending on where you want the changelog to appear, there is probably a more reliable way to get it.

Comment: @digout : do you mean that you save a log of your git repo inside your git repo ?

Comment: Sounds scary to me. Might work if you are the only contributor for the project, however I still wouldn't do it. You already have the changelog in git, not sure what you hope to achieve by duplicating this into another file. In general the git changelog often documents changes to a very detailed level and is not suitable for the changelog file.

Comment: @digout : what's your use case ? as some others have said, I think you can easily find another way to do that.  
One example : instead of versioning this log, use your script to produce the log output when *deploying* your code.

Comment: If you want an accurate git log that reflects the true log as it appears on git, and not a copy that can be made invalid via a log message edit, then you should be retrieving the git log by pulling it directly from git each and every time instead of attempting to duplicate it.

Comment: @PenguinBrian the use case is just really to allow others in the team to catchup on updates to the project. I am the only developer so saving time in using my commit logs is appealing to me. The repo is hosted by Beanstalk who in turn deploys the files so no direct access to query the log another way. Ok I could open up an SSH connection to send the file but I thought that would add more complication compared to this way.

Comment: @JanHudec Probably? I'm open to suggestions. I am the only dev, it doesn't matter that it's local only. If the commit hook can do some hokery pokery and remove the previous log file first would that get around some of the issue of merging?

Comment: @digout, the usual approach is to generate the change long when checking out to the server, so it is not stored in a versioned file at all.

Comment: I'd really consider making the git repository available. It isn't hard to push another copy to github or gitlab or something. git is distributed. If there is a reason you don't want to make the git repository available, e.g. you don't want to publish the entire history of your project, you probably don't want to publish the entire git changelog either. In this case, better to edit a changelog by hand so you choose what gets published.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to create an appropriate hook that writes the changelog to a file *outside* your repo, and then pushes the file to somewhere accessible by external users. No need to commit the changelog then, which is the cause of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Given your use case, I would suggest :
move your `pre-commit` hook on your local machine to the `post-checkout` hook on the dashboard server (I imagine there is a clone of the repo behind that dashboard site ?)

Comment: No, the files are deployed to the 'dashboard server' from a repo hoster (Beanstalk)